# Why do we have to use an intermediary variable for @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

Tags: java, suppress-warnings

Good afternoon all,

I was wondering what's the reason that

```
public class test<T> {
    T[] backing_array;

    public void a(int initial_capacity) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] backing_array = (T[]) new Object[initial_capacity];
        this.backing_array = backing_array;
    }
}
```

is valid but

```
public class test<T> {
    T[] backing_array;

    public void b(int initial_capacity) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        this.backing_array = (T[]) new Object[initial_capacity];
    }
}
```

is a syntax/compiler error?

What's the reason that we have to use an intermediary variable for `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` ?

Comment: mmm..same here but if you moved the SuppressWarning to before the class block, it is fine though.. +1 for this.

Comment: @Jasonw, from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html: _"As a matter of style, programmers should always use this annotation on the most deeply nested element where it is effective. If you want to suppress a warning in a particular method, you should annotate that method rather than its class."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is applied on the scope of the declaration and assignment right after it. It can be assigned to functions' scope, or a specific variable's assignment.
In your first example, it is applied on the local variable. In the 2nd example, you're trying to apply it on an assignment of a field that was already declared.

See that this also doesn't compile:

```
public class Test<T> {

    public void a(int initial_capacity) {
        T[] backing_array;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        backing_array = (T[]) new Object[initial_capacity];
    }
}
```

and this has no effect on warnings:

```
public class Test<T> {

    public void a(int initial_capacity) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] backing_array;
        backing_array = (T[]) new Object[initial_capacity];
    }
}
```

In short, SuppressWarnings cannot be applied on a variable's throughout its scope. It's applied on an assignment+decleration (for variables) or on the entire method's scope when applied on a method.

Answer (score 5):

Because you can only annotate:

- classes
- methods
- variables
- parameters
- packages

You cannot annotate expressions or statements.

Comment: And sometimes only a subset of those if the `@Target(ElementType[])` annotation is used.

Answer (score 1):

Compiles OK for me (simplified to remove irrelevant code):

```
public static class Test<T> {
    T[] array;

    public void a() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] a = (T[]) new Object[1];
        this.array = a;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void b() {
        this.array = (T[]) new Object[1];
    }
}
```

The only observation of note is that the `@SuppressWarnings` goes on the *method* rather than the code line in `b()` due to the suppression being on a *field* assignment rather than *local variable* assignment

Comment: deleted an earlier comment, which was written prior to your edit :) +1 for a nice explanation

Comment: @Bohemian but for my case there are other statements in the method `b` and I would like to keep SuppressWarnings as scoped as possible.