# Java Generics: Why does my @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") work in this case, but not the other?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Question is similar to this [Why do we have to use an intermediary variable for @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076083/why-do-we-have-to-use-an-intermediary-variable-for-suppresswarningsunchecked), but I couldn't glean a solution from that one.

As an exercise, I'm building a hash-table construct from scratch. So I wrote a class LinkedListDemo auxiliary to HashTableDemo; the LinkedListDemo class tests absolutely fine. Particularly, the following subroutine in causes no ClassCastException errors at run-time:

```
    public LinkedListDemo<S, T> reverse() {

        if (count == 0)
            return null;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        S[] keys = (S[]) new Object[count];
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] vals = (T[]) new Object[count];

        ListNode<S, T> runner = head;
        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {

            keys[k] = runner.pair.getKey();
            vals[k] = runner.pair.getValue();

            runner = runner.next;

        }

        ArrayUtils.reverse(keys);
        ArrayUtils.reverse(vals);

        return new LinkedListDemo<S, T>(keys, vals);

    }
```

Whereas the following, in my HashTable class does:

```
public class HashTableDemo<S, T> {

    private LinkedListDemo<S, T>[] table = (LinkedListDemo<S, T>[]) new Object[10]; 

// more code...

}
```

Does anyone know how Java's HashMap class circumvents this issue, and/or how I can? I tried creating an intermediate variable within a constructor as suggested in the above link - but it didn't work.

Comment: You *should* be getting ClassCastExceptions at runtime.  Maybe you're not testing thoroughly.  The assignment `S[] keys = (S[]) new Object[count];` is only legal if `S` is `Object`.  It will fail if `S` is, say `String`.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot Not true, since `S` is erased to `Object` - this is the meaning of an *unchecked* cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will compile:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // this is okay because [insert reasoning here]
private LinkedListDemo<S, T>[] table =
        (LinkedListDemo<S, T>[]) new LinkedListDemo<?, ?>[10];
```

The reason your code errors is because an `Object[]` is not a `LinkedListDemo[]`, similarly to how an `Object` is not a `LinkedListDemo`.

The earlier unchecked casts work because `S[]` and `T[]` have been [*erased*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to `Object[]` at runtime.

In general, arrays of parameterized types are discouraged because their very existence is unsafe. This is because:

- Arrays are covariant - a `LinkedListDemo<S, T>[]` *is* an `Object[]`. So one could assign `table` to an `Object[]` variable and then assign a `String` as an element - this would be legal at compile time but would at least fail at runtime with an `ArrayStoreException`, since arrays do runtime type checking.
- Generic type information is not available at runtime because it's been erased by the compiler. One could once again assign `table` to an `Object[]` variable but this time assign a `LinkedListDemo<String, Integer>` as an element. At runtime, the array would only see that a plain `LinkedListDemo` had been added, so it would *not* fail right away if the generic types were wrong. This might lead to unexpected `ClassCastException`s at some later time.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957325/generic-types-in-an-array-for-a-tree-with-more-than-one-child/15962718#15962718) for a fuller explanation and example of this issue. See also this great explanation by Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ: [Can I create an array whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?)

The takeaway is that it will be much easier and safer to simply use a `List<LinkedListDemo<S, T>>` instead. If you ultimately decide to stick to using `LinkedListDemo<S, T>[]`, make sure that it is carefully hidden as an implementation detail and stay cognizant about how it can be misused.

A couple of other misc notes:

- `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` doesn't *do* anything but suppress the unchecked cast compiler warning. It's essentially saying "trust me I know what I'm doing" - but you still need to be careful that an unchecked cast isn't being misused. See this post for more info: [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)
- Like all core API classes, the [source for `HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java) is available so you should feel free to look over it if you want to understand its inner workings better.

Comment: Thanks Paul; but by extension, why isn't LinkedListDemo similarly erased at run-time?

Comment: @VictorAlvarez `LinkedListDemo` is a *reifiable* type, meaning it's still available at runtime. `LinkedListDemo<S, T>[]` gets erased to `LinkedListDemo[]`.

Comment: Is it reifiable because it itself holds type parameters, as opposed to S and T which are themselves type parameters? Thanks -

Comment: @VictorAlvarez It's reifiable because it's *not* itself a generic type argument or type parameter. Generic type arguments get erased, e.g. `LinkedListDemo<S, T>[]` or `LinkedListDemo<String, Integer>[]` to `LinkedListDemo[]`. Type parameters get erased, e.g. `S` to `Object`.

Comment: If Class<T> is a type-parametrized class, then Class<T>[] is erased to Class[] at runtime, as you say. But how does the computer interpret a parametrized class with no parameter, as in "Class[]"?

Comment: @VictorAlvarez When type erasure happens, the appropriate casts are added into the compiled bytecode. So given `Class<MyType> c`, which is going to erase to `Class c`, the code `MyType obj = c.newInstance();` compiles into something like `MyType obj = (MyType)c.newInstance();` (except in bytecode). See this post for more info: [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens).